# Dynamic categories in index page with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I want to give option to admins in order to edit their index page by adding products from different category.

## Explanation

Admin can choose categories from their panel and regarding to that category products in it will show as section in index page.

admin select `category 1`, in `index` we have new section include `category 1` products. and so on.

index will be like:

> category 1 section `10` products.
>
> category 2 section `10` products.
>
> category 3 section `10` products.
>
> category 4 section `10` products.
>
> category 5 section `10` products.

and admin can add or remove these sections.

## Code:

Currently I only have static section in my index where I get latest products from all categories, i want to have products of each category separately in that section.

this is my function in `AppServiceProvider`

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
          $productsone = DB::table('products')
          ->latest()
          ->take(10)
          ->get();
          $view->with('productsone', $productsone);
        });
```

and i get my data in index page with `@foreach($productsone as $product)`.

**ps: please share idea with me how i can do that, if i need to create tables etc.**

## update:

My issue is not in query, what i want is to know how to build the system to let admin choose `unlimited` category and pop those category sections in `index` page. (is really something like `WordPress` themes *some of them* that you can select categories and show posts of that in index)

### sample

[image: img1]

look at those `nature` and `culture`. They are category sections in index page.

## UPDATE 2

I've made new table:

```
Schema::create('admin_designs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::table('admin_designs', function($table) {
           $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
           $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
        });
```

And I've saved some rows in it.

problem i'm facing during to test this way works or not is that i cannot get my products list. `WHY?` because my products are not stored under my `categories` they are stored by `subcategories`.

I need kind of query that says:

1. look in `admin_desings` table `category_id` column
2. get that id and match it with `subcategories` table where the
   subcategories have same `id` in `category_id` column
3. then match it with `products` table where they have those
   `subcategories` id

in that way i can get products under selected category regardless of what subcategory they are in.

**This is my broken function! :)**

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
   $category = Category::with('admin_designs')->where('id', 'category_id')->get();
   $subcategory = Subcategory::where('category_id', $category)->get();
   $designs = AdminDesign::with('products')
      ->where('subcategory_id', $category)
      ->orderby('id', 'desc')
      ->latest()
      ->take(10)
      ->get();
            
$view->with('designs', $designs);
});
```

Error i'm getting on this query is:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from
> `subcategories` where `category_id` = ?)

Comment: use `where` clause on your query, or much better, create a relationship between `category` and `products`

Comment: @mafortis did you have category table if yes join both table and then do forloop in blade foreg  DB::table('products')->join('category','product.id','=','category.id)
          ->latest()
          ->take(10)
          ->get();

Comment: @Wreigh you didn't get my point bro, my issue is not in query, what i want is to know how to build the system to let admin choose `unlimited` category and pop those category sections in `index` page.

Comment: @bipin you didn't get my point bro, my issue is not in query, what i want is to know how to build the system to let admin choose `unlimited` category and pop those category sections in `index` page.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: @mafortis did you want something like this eg admin select category1 then it should show in index blade now admin select another category2 then index should have category1 as well as category 2 ? Am I right

Comment: @bipin exactly.

Comment: @mofortis foreach(Category as category) in index page and when admin click on category1 then pass parameters category1 from route to controller and do query why you are not doing like this

Comment: In this case store new category in table by admin

Comment: @bipin honestly? i'm a bit confused by your comment. Would you mind to share an answer and explain it more?

Comment: @mafortis is that you want I had given a answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

I added new table to database and save each category id as i wish to show in index page, then i get products under that category by code below in my `appserviceprovider`

```
View::composer('welcome', function ($view) {
            $category = DB::table('admin_designs')
                              ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'admin_designs.category_id')
                              ->join('subcategories', 'subcategories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                              ->join('products', 'products.subcategory_id', '=', 'subcategories.id')
                                ->get();

            $view->with('category', $category);
        });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In you blade:

```
@foreach($cat as $c)
    //your html or just example of image
    <a href="{{url('catid',$c->I'd)}}"><Img src="I'm going.jpg">< /a>
@endforeach
@If(!$pro==null) 
    @foreach($pro as $p)
    @endforeach
@endif
```

In route:

```
Route::get('catid/{Id}',Controller@display);
```

In you controller:

```
Public function index(){ 
    $cat=DB::table('category')->get();
    $pro=null;
    Return view('index');
}
Public function display($id){ 
    $cat=DB::table('category')->get();
    $pro = DB::table('products')
       ->where('categoryid',$id)
       ->latest()
       ->take(10)
       ->get();
    Return view('index',compact('pro');
}
```

Comment: what about storing this data? should i create new table?  this is about returning results which i'll place it in `AppServiceProvider` but for admin part? to select categories i mean?

Comment: @mafortis for admin side insert category name and other details which you want

Comment: @mafortis you can https://github.com/lvntayn/laravel-social-network refer his code of notification you can use that thing instead of appserviceprovider

Comment: i didn't get it! which part you mean?

Comment: @mafortis instead of using appservice provider there is other way above link has that other way if you his code what he had used for notification you will get what I  mean

Comment: I didn't find that you mentioned so i continued with provider. I updated my question please take a look at it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164306/discussion-between-bipin-and-mafortis).